React Native Webview Component Rendering CSS issues
UPDATE: The app was using vpn before and now it is not. So the change is that the app is not going thru vpn and the css are acting weird.
I am using a react native webview component to render a website.  I made some changes to my build process because it was breaking.  I updated my cocoapods version, my ruby version, react natieve from 0.71.14 to 0.71.19 and that was it.
My app which is in prod is working fine and now with the new build my site css styles are not working correctly.  Some of my css style dont seem to apply the first time my app opens.  I then close the app and open it again and my css styles seem to render fine.
I have reverted my react native version and also have tried different versions of the webview component.  No luck.  Anyone has any idea?  I checked webview repo for issues on this and i do not see anything close to wht i am facing. Any help is appreciated.
